# Как составить список уникальных числовых комбинаций разделённых пробелами

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, комбинаторика

Мне нужно составить список уникальных числовых комбинаций которые нужно будет разделить пробелами через каждый третий символ.
Я нашел такой вариант:

```
test = list(itertools.combinations('0123456789', 9))
```

Получается список кортежей:

```
[('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'), ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9') ...
```

Ума не приложу как его можно превратить в такой список:

```
['012 345 678', '012 345 679', '012 345 689', ...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста какой нибудь способ решить эту задачку?

Comment: Почему числа объединяются в группы по три элемента?

Comment: Уточню на всякий(['012 345 678', '012 345 679', '012 345 689', ...) - это я вручную набрал, как бы пример, как то так хотелось бы получить в итоге. А если вообще, то нужно для тестирования нагенерировать именно в таком виде что бы потом подставлять в файлик

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

a = list(itertools.combinations('0123456789', 9))
b =[[''.join(y[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(y), 3)] for y in a]
res = [' '.join(x) for x in b]
print(res)
```

> ['012 345 678', '012 345 679', '012 345 689', '012 345 789', '012 346 789', '012 356 789', '012 456 789', '013 456 789', '023 456 789', '123 456 789']

Comment: Супер, спасибо!